# postgresql 11 docker create custom database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to create custom scripts which will create database connect to it and initialise the schema. So I've created following shell scripts:

file: `100_sample_create.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/tablespaces/SAMPLECLIENT
mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/tablespaces/SAMPLEINDEX
set -e
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
  CREATE ROLE SAMPLEOWNER;
  CREATE USER SAMPLE WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'samplepwd';
  GRANT SAMPLEOWNER TO SAMPLE;
  CREATE TABLESPACE SAMPLECLIENT OWNER SAMPLEOWNER LOCATION '/var/lib/postgresql/tablespaces/SAMPLECLIENT';
  CREATE TABLESPACE SAMPLEINDEX OWNER SAMPLEOWNER LOCATION '/var/lib/postgresql/tablespaces/SAMPLEINDEX';
  CREATE DATABASE SAMPLE OWNER SAMPLEOWNER ENCODING 'UTF-8' TABLESPACE SAMPLECLIENT CONNECTION LIMIT -1;
EOSQL
```

file: `110_sample_init.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "SAMPLEOWNER" --dbname "SAMPLE" <<-EOSQL
  CREATE SCHEMA SAMPLE;
  ALTER SCHEMA SAMPLE OWNER TO SAMPLEOWNER;
  ALTER DATABASE SAMPLE SET search_path TO SAMPLE;
  ALTER ROLE SAMPLEOWNER SET search_path TO SAMPLE;
  ALTER ROLE SAMPLEOWNER SET default_tablespace = SAMPLECLIENT;
  GRANT ALL ON DATABASE SAMPLE TO SAMPLEOWNER;
  GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA SAMPLE TO SAMPLEOWNER;
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA SAMPLE TO SAMPLEOWNER;
EOSQL
```

file `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  sample-postgres:
    image: "postgres:11"
    container_name: "sample-postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password1.
    volumes:
      - ./100_sample_create.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/100_sample_create.sh
      - ./110_sample_init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/110_sample_init.sh
```

however when I start the container I'm getting following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/110_sample_init.sh
2019-05-22 13:56:05.603 UTC [72] FATAL:  role "SAMPLEOWNER" does not exist
psql: FATAL:  role "SAMPLEOWNER" does not exist
```

does it mean that user was created only in `$POSTGRES_DB` database and is not available in `SAMPLE` db? How should I change the scripts to properly create custom db and initialise it? I know that I can customise the name of db with docker parameters, but I want to do this by scripts because I need to have more databases inside container.

Comment: From documentation: ` You must have CREATEROLE privilege or be a database superuser to use this command` , are you a superuser or have the privilege? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createrole.html

Comment: to which problem is your comment? Role SAMPLEOWNER should be created as there was no error in execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you used:

```
CREATE ROLE SAMPLEOWNER;
```

creates a role named sampleowner (all lower case).  If you really want it to be upper case, use:

```
CREATE ROLE "SAMPLEOWNER";
```

Comment: thanks, additional thing  was to add `LOGIN` to role `SAMPLEOWNER` creation script.

Comment: Yes, because it is created as a role, it won't have login privileges by default.  If you swap out the word ROLE for USER, it will get those privileges by default (that's the only difference between the two commands).